# Swift - How to resize UICollectionViewCells after image is downloaded from URL?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS app that has a collection view.  The size of the collection view cells (instagram photos) are configured to be perfect squares, but the client does not want cropped images, so I am trying to create a completion handler in the cell class which will send a call back to a method defined in my view controller through a delegate which will send back a CGSize I can work with.

The code uses the [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) Library to download the images

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher


class InstagramPostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var delegate: CellResizeDelegate?

func setupForInstagramPost(_ post: InstagramPost, delegate: CellResizeDelegate) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.imageView.kf_setImage(with: URL(string:post.imageURL)!)
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.delegate = delegate
}
}
```

I checked out the definition for this line:

```
self.imageView.kf_setImage(with: URL(string:post.imageURL)!)
```

and found that it takes in a completion handler:

```
  public func kf_setImage(with resource: Resource?, placeholder: Image? = default, options: KingfisherOptionsInfo? = default, progressBlock: Kingfisher.DownloadProgressBlock? = default, completionHandler: Kingfisher.CompletionHandler? = default) -> Kingfisher.RetrieveImageTask
```

How do I define a custom completion handler in the InstagramPostCell class to use the delegate to send the CGSize of the newly downloaded image back to the View Controller?

I hope that makes sense

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 0):

found a solution

```
self.imageView.kf_setImage(with: URL(string:post.imageURL)!, completionHandler:{
        (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
    })
```